# Error in applet in the navigator with fingerprint reader

Tags: applet, browser, fingerprint

First thank you very much for your time, I have a problem with the development of an applet to control users via fingerprint, as developed in eclipse using the DigitalPersona SDK, the problem is when I run it from a web page browser,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.JniException
 at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture._impl.DPFPCaptureFactoryImpl$CaptureImpl.startCapture(DPFPCaptureFactoryImpl.java:187)
 at CDesVerifinger.formComponentShown(CDesVerifinger.java:76)
 at CDesVerifinger.access$1(CDesVerifinger.java:73)
 at CDesVerifinger$1.componentShown(CDesVerifinger.java:64)
 at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

    Caused by: com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.JniException
 at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.AcquisitionLibrary.getInstance(AcquisitionLibrary.java:50)
 at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Acquisition.<init>(Acquisition.java:45)
 at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture._impl.DPFPCaptureFactoryImpl$CaptureImpl.startCapture(DPFPCaptureFactoryImpl.java:104)
 ... 16 more
```

Thank you very much for any help

good day

Comment: Changed title from Spanish to English. Not sure why OP did that since their command of English seems fine based on the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `dptojni.jar` to the library of your project, it is in `c:/programs files/digital persona/bin/java`. Or you can get the class `jniException` and add it to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem, [here](http://java.net/projects/cejug/lists/discussao/archive/2009-11/message/341) is someone telling that is necessary put

```
capturer.setPriority(DPFPCapturePriority.CAPTURE_PRIORITY_LOW);
```

after calling createCapture to solve it. I will try this answer now.

Comment: This work for me, but not after, instead before create.Capture

Answer (score 2):

You have to sign the jar files.  That's what I did, and now it's working.

Comment: did you use a personnal generated key to sign the jar?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have instatiated the DPFPCapture object before calling the setCapturePriority method and also make sure you stop capture after you have finished using the capture object